# Play! 2+ Adding JSON support in a RESTfull way

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, rest, playframework

I'm used to do ROR, but I need to make a RESTfull WebService in a Java environnement. So I decided to try it with Play! since it really look like a great idea.

So I'm trying to find a way to add JSON to my already existing firstapp done following those instruction : http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaTodoList

What I want is something working similarly to ROR. At least, I want to be able to ask for JSON support by :

- calling a .json URL
- using "Accept: application/json" Header

---

So I tried some dirty thing like that :

```
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    if(json != null) {
        return ok(Json.toJson(Task.all()));
    }

    return ok(
            views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm)
    );
```

And it's obviously not working right now...

---

I need to detect wich type the client is requiring. I saw some people were adding dirty routes like that :

```
    POST    /bars                                       BarController.index()
    GET     /bars.json                                  BarController.indexJSON()
```

But it will clearly not support client using header to specify json request...

---

So, what I need is some kind of way to find out if there is any Header specifing content-type or Accept application/json. If it is so, BarController.index() would return BarController.indexJSON()...

All in all, it would be pretty much similar to ROR wich do :

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @bars }
end
```

---

All in all :

Does anyone have gone through the same reasoning than me and had reach an end ?

Comment: what do you expect `request().body().asJson();` to return?

Comment: it return a JsonNode if body is JSON pasable...

Comment: so are you POSTing json to your service?

Comment: also, what do you mean "it's not working"? is `json` null?

Comment: Yeah, most of the time if you make GET on a Collection you just want to RETRIEVE it. So you don't send à JSON Body. But you send a HEADER:Accept: application/json...

Comment: in version 1.1, documentation contained http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/routes which explains content types and various methods. `request.headers.get("accept").value()` may help (i would use the .{format} method)

Comment: Yes and we were able to get the format with thing such as `GET    /index.{format}    Application.index ` But it don't know how to do it with Play!2 ...

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved my problem by using to function in controller, like this :

```
public static Result index()
public static Result indexJSON()
```

Then I added routes :

```
GET     /tasks                      controllers.TaskController.index()
GET     /tasks/json                 controllers.TaskController.indexJSON()
```

I would have preferred task.json but it wouldn't have allowed /tasks/:id.json ...

And for Header support, you need to check in your classic function if there is no header :

```
public static Result index() {
    if (request().getHeader(play.mvc.Http.HeaderNames.ACCEPT).equalsIgnoreCase("application/json") || request().getHeader(Http.HeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE).equalsIgnoreCase("application/json")) {
        return indexJSON();
    }
    else {
        return ok(
                views.html.index.render(Task.all(), taskForm)
        );
    }
}
```

End that's all folks !

Does anybody have a better solution ? I don't like this one very much... Because I'm going to repeat many code ...

Comment: if i read you correctly, you don't even need the task.json route? Also, tasks.{format}, i guess you receive a format variable in your method somewhere ?

Comment: what are you going to repeat?

Comment: I need the task.json because some lowREST client don't use the correct header.
I tried task format. And the route isn't valid :
` For request 'GET /tasks.json'
These routes have been tried, in this order:

1GET/assets/$file<.+>controllers.Assets.at(path:String = "/public", file:String)

2GET/task.{format}controllers.TaskController.index()

3POST/task.{format}controllers.TaskController.newTask()

4POST/tasks/$id<[^/]+>/deletecontrollers.TaskController.deleteTask(id:Long)`